# How to resize an Rectangle accordingly with a TextField?

Tags: java, resize, javafx, shapes, fxml

I want to resize an Rectangle shape from JavaFX accordingly with a TextField which automatically resize on Window resize using Anchors.

I tried add anchors to the rectangle also but it won't resize from the width I set from SceneBuilder.

So short story: when my TextField resizes because my Window resize the Rectangle should resize to the same width as the TextField. Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the rectangle's width to the text field's:

```
myRectangle.widthProperty().bind(myTextField.widthProperty());
```

Example:

```
public class Demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        TextField myTextField = new TextField("default");
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRectangle.setHeight(30);
        myRectangle.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        myRectangle.widthProperty().bind(myTextField.widthProperty());

        final VBox hb = new VBox(10);
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        hb.getChildren().addAll(myTextField, myRectangle);
        scene.setRoot(hb);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```